# Need guidance with model association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to access the scores from a specific Organization. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direct of being able to accomplish this. I currently have the following Models:

Here is the User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :fname, :lname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
 has_secure_password
 belongs_to :organization
```

Here is the Organization Model

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :employee_number, :country, :postal_code, :sic_code, :primary_url
 has_many :users
 has_many :social_entities
 has_many :social_scores, :through => :social_entity  
 has_many :social_channels, :through => :social_entity
```

Here is the Entity Model

```
class SocialEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :org_id
 has_many :social_channels
 has_many :social_scores  
 belongs_to :organization
```

Here is the Channel Model

```
class SocialChannel < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :authorized, :channel_identifier, :channel_type, :name, :social_entity_id
 belongs_to :social_entity  # edited from original post, :socialentity
```

Here is the Score Model

```
class SocialScore < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :engagement_score, :popularity_score, :presence_score, :reputation_score,   :score_period_end, :score_period_start, :score_period_type, :score_timestamp, :social_entity
 belongs_to :social_entity
```

Here is a description of what I am trying to do. A User logs into the system, the user is tied to a organization, each organization has a social entity which has social channels and scores. I want to be able to display the scores for the organization in the view.

Comment: Look at these examples http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Comment: I think you would have to describe what you are trying to accomplish to know if this is right.  Edit your question to add a paragraph describing what each of these things is, and that might help us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an instance of Organization, the `has_many` declaration creates an attribute (a method, really) that gets a collection of SocialScores, referenced by `social_scores`, e.g.

```
@org = Organization.find(:first)  # or however else it is that you get the organization instance
@org.social_scores.each do |ss|
   puts "Popularity score for id #{ss.id} is #{ss.popularity_score}"
end
```

Is that what you were seeking?

Comment: I think so. I'm really new to this so I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: So, this is what I was looking for however how would I access the most recent score for a specific entity